# Error in Web Service when Deployed to DMZ

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I have a webservice which I can get to run on my computer, but when deployed to a webserver (in a DMZ) it doesn't work.

When running the service on the web server, it shows a WSDL and singleWSDL that seemingly appear to be correct. Using the singleWSDL in SoapUI to test the service returns the following error message

> The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the
>   action 'http://tempuri.org/IService1/TestStringContract' is incorrect
>   or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context
>   token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security
>   context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due
>   to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions
>   prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's
>   binding.

From what I gather, the most likely cause, is an issue in the App.Config file, which I have detailed herein

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="MyService.Service1Behavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:{port}/MyService.Service1.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="http://{external_ip}:{port}/MyService.Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyService.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="EquitaWcfCbl.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="10"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpGetUrl="http://{external_ip}:{port}/EquitaWcfCblMyService.Service1.svc/mex"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**[update @ 2014-02-19 1400hrs]**

With further research continually pointing that the setup of the App.Config; I decided to pull out the current App.Config file and start it again, from scratch, using the WCF Service Configuration Editor, which is built into Visual Studio (tools menu) adding in the information a piece at a time and testing progress, which resulted in a working service with the following App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior1">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceMetadata 
            httpGetEnabled="true" 
            httpGetUrl=" http://{externalip}:{port}/MyService.Service1.svc/mex"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service 
        behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior1" 
        name="EquitaWcfCbl.TabletService">
        <endpoint 
          address="http://{externalip}:{port}/MyService.Service1.svc/mex" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" 
          name="ServiceEndpoint1" 
          contract=" MyService.Service1" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I'm not (yet) entirely convinced that this is exactly what we need, but with a working service ... I can at least progress.

Comment: What does this have to do with schemaLocation?

Comment: Edited - was posting a different question and forgot to change the subject.